# Get object include DateTimeField in Django

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

When I have a model, it has DateTimeField in fields.

I get one object from the model and get the attribute of DateTimeField.

It has tzinfo of UTC.

Example:

> datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 21, 14, 18, 27, tzinfo=`<UTC>`)

What are possible to display other timezones except UTC?

Comment: I don't understand - `What times does it appear except UTC?`. Are you asking what other timezones are possible ?

Comment: @AJK Yes, I'm sorry that I express badly. I had edited it.

Comment: It's still not clear. All timezones are possible, surely.

Comment: @DanielRoseman What are possible to display other timezones except UTC?

Answer (score 0):

The python `datetime` module can be used to convert time zones from one to another.

here's the documentation on tzinfo - https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#tzinfo-objects

It's pretty smart and can accpet time zone names or even country names

`“GMT”, “UTC”, “-500”, “-5:00”, “EDT”, “US/Eastern”, “America/New York”` - from the coumentation

---

You can create a new datetime using:

```
a = datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 21, 14, 18, 27, tzinfo=<UTC>)
a.replace(tzinfo="EST")
```

You cannot change the tzinfo as datetime objects are immutable

Comment: Then I think you may need to explain a bit more clearly as to what you want.